# Remove the background layer of UIImageview

Tags: iphone, background, uiimageview

I searched everywhere but didn't find the solution. I have image 1. How can I programatically adjust the background layer of UIImageView?

Please look at the below image.

And my question is: how can I achieve this effect programatically?[image]

Comment: what the mean of background layer

Comment: I asume you want to make an `UIImage` transparent by removing (chroma keying) a specific color?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps:
[How can I change the color 'white' from a UIImage to transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458303/how-can-i-change-the-color-white-from-a-uiimage-to-transparent)

it replaces a white color with a transparent 'color'. Ofcourse you have to tweak it for your personal use