# Remove white pixels from uiimageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, cgcolor

I am new to IOS Development. I have an `UIImageView` and I want to remove the white color pixels in my image view. Is this possible to remove the white color pixels.

Comment: Do you want to replace your white color with clear color ?? And do you want to remove UIImageView's white color or UIImage's white color ???

Comment: Hi Rathore,  I want to remove UIImageView's white color or UIImage's white color.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9460940/468724 hope this will help you